# Jquery Cycle2 not initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

I was setting up a slideshow using the first version of cycle and then thought I'd update to the newest version, but once I linked the file, my slideshow broke.  I'm not sure why it is working in version 1 but not 2.  I even get a console message : [cycle2] --c2 init-- .

Ideas?

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span1">
        <div class="chevron">
            <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="slide-show-container noselect">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div id="highcharts01"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div id="highcharts02"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Landscape-wallpapers-1.jpeg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <div class="chevron">
            <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="slideNav">
    <div class="offset1 span8 noselect" id="circleNav">

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.slide-show-container').cycle({ 
fx:    'fade', 
speed:  500,
timeout: 0,
next: ".icon-chevron-right",
prev: ".icon-chevron-left",
pager: "#circleNav",
after: initCharts
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What are the differences between your code, and the one below?

- Deleted `after: initCharts` and `timeout: 0` from your JS.
- Added `jquery.cycle.all.js` and `jquery.min.js`
- Added `position: relative;` to `.slide-show-container`
- Added `position: absolute;` and `z-index: 5;` for images

It's working now, however I guess your pagers won't show up because I don't have the CSS containing the images for divs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide-show-container').cycle({
 fx:    'fade',
        speed:  500,
        next: ".icon-chevron-right",
        prev: ".icon-chevron-left",
        pager: "#circleNav"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1">
        <div class="chevron">
            <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="slide-show-container noselect" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" width="180" height="180" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5;"/>
            </div>
            
            <div class="slide">
                <div id="highcharts01"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div id="highcharts02"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Landscape-wallpapers-1.jpeg" width="180" height="180" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <div class="chevron">
            <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="slideNav">
    <div class="offset1 span8 noselect" id="circleNav" >

    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that someway I could help with this, also you wanted something like this.

Comment: Adding jquery.cycle.all.js seemed to fix everything.  What is that file supposed to be?  A combination of the previous 2 versions or a newer version?  By the way, thanks for your help!

Comment: It is used by the version 1 with transition definitions. It's not a new version, it's actually old and needs jQuery 1.7.1 or higher only. Also you could try adding `<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>` into your HTML.